# Why are panelGridLayouts overlapping?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am building a form which contains two forms adjacent to each other. Hence I used `PanelGridLayout` and placed two `panelFormLayout` in each 50% width `gridCell` of first `gridRow` of a `PanelGridLayout`. This works perfect with respect to alignment but in a smaller resolution both the `gridcell's` are overlapping and the fields of left form are overlapping with the labels of the right form.

How can I resolve this issue?

Any ideas on which layouts I can use?

Answer (score 0):

What would you expect it to do in such a case where there is basically not enough space to show the fields in one of the sides?
ADF won't automatically shrink or eliminate fields in such a case.

Comment: will i be able to get a scroll bar instead of these overlaps? Which layout will help me achieve this?

Comment: which is the best layout to use in case I want to stretch the components inside?

Comment: If you want a scroll bar then see if surrounding the content in each column with a panelGroupLayout helps.

Answer (score 0):

Acc to the Geometry Management of <af:gridCell>

- Beware that if you attempt to use width="auto", halign="center", halign="end" in conjunction with cell content that uses unstable, percentage-based widths, you may experience different results in different browsers. If you wish to use these settings, be sure to constraint the width of that cell content.
  Possible Workaround

instead of halign="end" change it to halign="stretch"

source : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/apirefs.111230/e17491/tagdoc/af_gridCell.html

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69374266/10871073) to multiple questions.

Comment: Hi @AdrianMole Both questions are similar