# gridCells are overlapping in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a grisRow & within that I have 2 gridCell

In the first one, a description is displayed.
In the second cell, an action icon is displayed.

But the description is touching or overlapping with the icon.

How can I avoid this.

```
<af:gridCell width="50%" id="gc2" valign="top"
             halign="start" marginStart="4px" marginEnd="10px">
    <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl2">
        <af:link id="ot11" text="#{row.name}"
                 clientComponent="true"
                 partialSubmit="true" styleClass="list-hdr-fields"
                 shortDesc="#{userinterfaceBundle.MANAGE_ROLES_LABEL}">
            <af:clientAttribute name="uId"
                                value="#{row.name}"/>
            <af:showPopupBehavior popupId="::manageRolesPopup"
                                  triggerType="click"/>
        </af:link>
        <af:outputText value="#{row.description}"
                       shortDesc="#{userinterfaceBundle.DESCRIPTION_LABEL}"
                       id="ot12" />

        <f:facet name="footer"/>
    </af:panelFormLayout>
</af:gridCell>
<af:gridCell width="25%" id="gc3" valign="middle"
             halign="end" marginStart="40px">
    <af:panelGroupLayout styleClass="lv-row-col-right"
                         id="pgl2">
        <af:panelGroupLayout styleClass="lv-row-col"
                             id="pgl16">
            <af:link id="l4"
                     icon="/oracle/ics/webconsole/view/images/func_preferences-new_16_ena.png"
                     disabledIcon="/oracle/ics/webconsole/view/images/func_preferences-new_16_dis.png"
                     hoverIcon="/oracle/ics/webconsole/view/images/func_preferences-new_16_hov.png"
                     depressedIcon="/oracle/ics/webconsole/view/images/func_preferences-new_16_act.png"
                     iconPosition="trailing"
                     shortDesc="#{userinterfaceBundle.ACTIONS_LABEL}">

            </af:link>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
</af:gridCell>
</af:gridRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using af:panelGroupLayout with layout="horizontal" instead of af:panelFormLayout

Comment: af:panelGroupLayout doesn't support the attribute orientation.

Comment: That didn't help. The description is almost touching the icon. Is there a way to add some space in between cells.

Comment: you can try <af:spacer height="10">

Answer (score 0):

add an af:spacer next to the component you need space next to and surround with panelGroup layout horizontal.
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_spacer.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the Geometry Management of <af:gridCell>:

> Beware that if you attempt to use width="auto", halign="center",
> halign="end" in conjunction with cell content that uses unstable,
> percentage-based widths, *you may experience different results in
> different browsers.* If you wish to use these settings, be sure to
> constraint the width of that cell content.

Possible Workaround: instead of `halign="end"`, change it to `halign="stretch"` ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/apirefs.111230/e17491/tagdoc/af_gridCell.html)).